# Launching jar file on Azure virtual machine

Tags: java, bash, azure, ssh, jar

I am developing a java server-like application (though it is not a server itself, more like a bot for social network) and I decided to use Azure virtual machine to deploy the app on. So I've chosen Ubuntu virtual machine. I successfully uploaded .jar file on server, connected to it with Bash shell for Windows and SSH (as described in manual for Azure). Then I am able to launch my file with `java -jar server.jar` and it works. But the problem is that when I close the shell on my home computer, the app shuts down on the server too. So my question is how to launch .jar file in the way where it won't exit once I close SSH session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command in the background with `nohup`:

```
nohup java -jar server.jar &
```